# Reopening a namespaced class in ruby -- initialize overridden?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a class in a namespace with a few methods

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    class Baz
      def initialize(arg1, arg2, arg3)
        # do stuff
      end

      def delete
        File.delete(@path)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In my test environment, I don't want `delete` to delete any files, so in a `TestHelper`, I do this

```
class Foo::Bar::Baz
  def delete
    puts "no delete in test"
  end
end
```

When I initialize this class this in my test, I get `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0)`. That is, the initialize method of `Baz` is gone. And to be sure, if I take a look at `self` in my test helper, there are no methods defined at all for `Baz`. It's been completely overridden by the `class` keyword.

I can make it work by using `class_eval` instead of `class`, i,e.

```
Foo::Bar::Baz.class_eval do
  def delete
    # etc
  end
end
```

My question is, what is the difference? Why does the latter work but not the former?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think you're accidentally breaking the autoloader. Here's what I think is happening in your working case (using `.class_eval`):

1. Something, somewhere, loads code that defines `Foo::Bar` (you'd be getting other errors if this wasn't happening)
2. Test code is parsed; explicitly requires `TestHelper`
3. `TestHelper` references `Foo::Bar::Baz`, which does not exist
4. autoloader finds and loads `foo/bar/baz.rb`
5. `TestHelper` runs `class_eval` and redefines `#delete`
6. Test code runs

And here's my guess at the non-working case:

1. Again, something, somewhere, loads code that defines `Foo::Bar`
2. Test code is parsed; explicitly requires `TestHelper`
3. `TestHelper` **creates** `Foo::Bar::Baz`, since it didn't already exist
4. Test code runs

Notice in the second case the autoloader was never triggered, so your actual class definition is never loaded.

I'm not sure the best way to solve this. You could do an explicit require in your test, or just reference the class in your helper before redefining it:

```
Foo::Bar::Baz # trigger autoloading before we muck with the definition
class Foo::Bar::Baz
  def delete
    puts "no delete in test"
  end
end
```